# Whether the ModelPopUpExtender works oly with ajaxenabledwebsite 

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Whether the ModelPopUpExtender works oly with ajaxenabledwebsite ..

How to use the ModelPopUpExtender  in Normal WebPage (visual studio 2008)

in normal web page i have used scriptmanager,updatepanel, & modelpopupextender . but it showing me an empty page. Did i have to add any lines to my web.config?

wat should be added in web.config to make it visible and works out with normal web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelPopupExtender is part of Ajax Control Toolkit which is an open source project, you can not use ModelPopup extenser without ajax (ScriptManager) on the aspx page